# Computing average of non-zero values

Tags: python, list, numpy, optimization

I have lists from whose I what the average of non-zero values.

E.G

```
 [2,2,0,0,0] -> 2    
 [1,1,0,1,0]  -> 1  
 [0,0,0,9,0] -> 9    
 [2,3,0,0,0] -> 2.5
```

Current I'm doing this:

```
list_ = [1,1,0,1,0]  
non_zero = [float(v) for v in list_ if v>0]
averge = sum(non_zero)/len(non_zero)
```

How can I do this operation more efficiently?

Comment: Non-zero means `v!=0`. Where as in your case, `v>0` means positive numbers

Comment: Don't you have the input as list of lists, like : `[[2, 2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0 ....]]` or is it an array?

Answer (score 12):

If you start with a numpy array, you can use [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to filter the array, then take the mean:

```
a = np.array([2,3,0,0,0])
average = a[np.nonzero(a)].mean()
```

You could also filter by boolean indexing, which appears to be faster:

```
average = a[a!=0].mean()
```

You could also easily change the method above to filter for positive values by using `a>0`.

**Timings**

Using the following setup:

```
a = np.random.randint(100, size=10**6)
```

I get the following timings:

```
%timeit a[a!=0].mean()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.59 ms per loop

%timeit a[a.nonzero()].mean()
100 loops, best of 3: 9.82 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a vectorized approach with summing after converting list of lists to a `2D` array -

```
from __future__ import division
a = np.asarray(list_)
a.sum(1)/(a!=0).sum(1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [32]: list_  #  Input list of lists
Out[32]: [[2, 2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 9, 0], [2, 3, 0, 0, 0]]

In [33]: a = np.asarray(list_) # Convert to array

In [34]: a.sum(1)/(a!=0).sum(1) # Divide row sums by count of non-zeros 
Out[34]: array([ 2. ,  1. ,  9. ,  2.5])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html):

```
l = np.array([2,2,0,0,0])

l[l.nonzero()].mean()
Out[17]: 2.0
```

---

A rough benchmark wrapping your current approach and this one in functions:

```
def luis_way(l):
    non_zero = [float(v) for v in l if v>0]
    average = sum(non_zero)/len(non_zero)
    return average

def np_way(l):
    return l[l.nonzero()].mean()



In [19]: some_l = np.random.randint(2, size=10000)
In [20]: %timeit luis_way(some_l)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.72 ms per loop
In [21]: %timeit np_way(some_l)
1000 loops, best of 3: 262 µs per loop
```

For small inputs, though, your current approach is probably fine. 
It is however worth noting that your current answer is not actually taking all non-zero elements, but only positive elements.

Comment: Hey, I'm only using positive numbers. But thanks for the flag, I didn't notice it.